# Plain Javascript: Do I really need wait document ready to attach event to elements?

Tags: javascript, events

It seems the following inline code works by putting js right after the tag:

```
   (1) 
   <div id="xx"></div>
    <script>
          document.getElementById('xx').addEventListener('click', aFunction);
    </script>
```

It seems there is no need to wait document ready like this:

```
    (2)
    <div id="xx"></div>
     <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
         document.getElementById('xx').addEventListener('click', aFunction);
    });
    </script>
```

Will the inline code (1) always work?

Please notice that I made sure `<div id="xx"></div>` is before the script.

Comment: You should wait till the document is loaded otherwise you will be finding an element named xx which is not yet loaded

Comment: good practice, thats how you want your page working.

Comment: `there is no need to wait document ready` - As it is impossible to attach events to elements directly which are not in the DOM (ignoring deferred binding) when do you think `DOMContentLoaded` executes! ? Please see [**Documentation on DOMContentLoaded**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) for details. `The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes` So if you want to interact with images you might have issues. #RTM

Comment: You don't _have to_ wait. You only have to be sure that every element you're going to modify is available in the DOM when the modifying script is executed.

Comment: Saw these related questions, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739853/is-it-really-necessary-to-wait-for-dom-ready-to-manipulate-the-dom?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222849/is-it-ok-to-manipulate-dom-before-ready-state?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: When you place your `<script>` tags before the closing `</body>` tags, it guarantees that the DOM is ready so `<script>` naturally loads right afterwards. 99% this works. 1% is certain DOM heavy plugins that need to be in the `<head>` instead. JWPlayer 6 and 7 is the only one I could never manage to do it with.

Answer (score -2):

You dont have to but you should. If you dont you will get errors when you try performing actions on elements in the dom when they havent been loaded yet, using document ready just ensures you dont have this issue, one less problem to debug basically.

Comment: How can 'they havent been loaded' if I put the script after the elements?

Comment: you usually wouldnt want to do that,  It is preferred to have your JavaScript stored externally